# Trouble parsing HTML table with Scrapy (Xpaths & Python)

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I would like to have Scrapy read an HTML table and return a CSV with the desired information extracted from the table.

Each item field corresponds with a th element within a tr. I think I am running into trouble with my xpaths, but I am not sure that I have used the selector correctly as well.

. . .

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    from scrapy.spiders import Spider
    from scrapy.selector import Selector

    from scraper_app.items import GenomeCanadaGrants

    class GCSpider(Spider):
        """Spider for Genome Canada Awards page."""
        name = 'GCSpider'
        allowed_domains = ["http://genomereports.ca"]
        start_urls= ["http://genomereports.ca/section.php?Action=List2&Lang=En&addnew=&Report=consolidated_commitments.php&Report_Text=Funding+Commitments&Nav=Section&ID=3&Login=&Password=&Consolidated_Centre=ALL&Consolidated_Category=ALL&Consolidated_Sector=ALL&Consolidated_Competition=ALL&Consolidated_FY=ALL&Consolidated_Status=ALL"]


def parse(self, response):

    sel = Selector(response)
    grants = sel.xpath('//html/body/table[1]/tr[]')
    items = []

    for response in grants:
        item = GenomeCanadaGrants()
        item['Province'] = response.xpath('./th[1]/text()').extract()  # Column Header: CENTRE
        item['Sector'] = response.xpath('./th[2]/text()').extract()  # Column Header: SECTOR
        item['Fund'] = response.xpath('./th[3]/text()').extract()  # Column Header: PROGRAM & Fiscal Yr Awarded
        item['Date'] = response.xpath('./th[3]/text()').re('\d+\d-\d+\d')  # Column Header: PROGRAM & Fiscal Yr Awarded
        item['Status'] = response.xpath('./th[4]/text()').extract  # Column Header: STATUS
        item['Principal_Investigator'] = response.xpath('./th[5]/text()').extract()  # Column Header: PROJECT LEADER(S)
        item['Project_Title'] = response.xpath("./th[6]/text()").extract  # Column Header: PROJECT TITLE
        item['Additional_Information'] = response.xpath("./th[7]//a[@href='url']").extract  # Link to PDF with Project Details
        item['Amount'] = response.xpath('./th[8]/text()').extrac  # Column Header: APPROVED BUDGET
        item['GC_Contribution'] = response.xpath('./th[9]/text()').extract  # Column Header: GC CONTRIBUTION
        items.append(item)

    return items
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's just that you are not locating the desired table correctly - it is inside the `div` with `id="content_frame"`.

Here is a sample code that works for me:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for row in response.css('div#content_frame table tr'):  
        try:
            cells = row.xpath(".//th//text()")
            first_cell = cells[0].extract()

            print(first_cell)
        except IndexError:
            continue  # it's just to skip rows not containing CENTRE value
```

Prints the contents of the first column:

```
CENTRE
Genome British Columbia
Genome British Columbia
Genome British Columbia
Genome Alberta
Genome Alberta
Genome Alberta
...
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I might have it now. Appreciate the help as I am new to both Xpaths & Scrapy.

Comment: So, I'm now able to get the same list for CENTREs that Alecxe retrieved, but some columns are populated with lines like this:

<bound method SelectorList.extract of [<Selector xpath='.//th[6]//text()' data=u'PROJECT TITLE'>]>

<bound method SelectorList.extract of [<Selector xpath='.//th[8]//text()' data=u'$6,806,270'>]>

Does anyone know what went wrong with these? In the second example, the extracted data I want is present along with code I do not want.

Comment: @RCran I think that both mine and Roshan's answers should give you a clearer picture now. See if you can accept one of the answers to resolve the topic.